# On the LEDs WS2812C

Tags: led

I've got a few questions about these LEDs (WS2812C). According to what I understand in the data sheet, they are adressable RGB LEDs with 4 pins: VCC, GND, DIN,DOUT. I'm working on a project that is an LED cube, and these LEDs are a very good candidate for my project, but I'm trying to figure out how I'm supposed to wire them (like how the circuit diagram should be).

So I have three questions:

1) is 1111 the maximum number of LEDs I can have in series? because the datasheet says that the maximum transfer rate is 800Kbps, and if I have to refresh the LEDs at a rate of 30 fps, and if my math is correct, 800Kbps/30fps/24bits = 1111 pixels. So please let me know if my math is correct on that, because that would imply that I would need two rows of LEDs if I were to make a 20x10x10 LED cube.

2) In the cicuit diagram of the datasheet there was only a capacitor and no resistor. According to what I know, you should always have a resistor in series with your LED, so that you don't blow it out. It is still the case with these?

3) Can I have one big capacitor instead of many small ones in parallel? I'd think that it would be equivalent but I'm not an expert so I don't know.

If any of you can help me figure out the answer to these questions I would highly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that the LEDs are suitable for a 3D layout?

Comment: the serial protocol has a reset signal of 50μs for each refresh, so the maximum LEDs would be 1109 for 30fps

Comment: if you know what you are doing, apparently you can drive [20,000+ WS2812C @ 130fps](https://hackaday.com/2019/05/07/lots-of-blinky-esp32-drives-20000-ws2812-leds/)

Comment: Ok, so to clear up a little how I'm going to make this cube happen, I am designing my own pcb and it's going to be a 5x5x5 cube to start, but I might make a bigger one in the future. Now I neeed to figure out the capacitor and resistor configuration for the pcb.

So do I need to have one capacitor (of value 15pF) per LED, or can I have one bigger capacitor (of value 15pF*n) for n LEDs?